# The relationship between light and magnetic fields

Tags: visible-light, magnetic-fields

I have two questions.

1. Does light have a magnetic field?
2. If not, can it be affected by other magnetic fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, light is a wavelike magnetic (and electric) field, so:

[image]

It practically doesn't interact with other magnetic fields.

In extreme circumstances (for example, around [magnetars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetar)) some interaction is possible.

They can also "interact" through the mediation of matter.

Comment: Does it oscillate at the wrong time compared to other magnetic or electric fields to interact with them?

Comment: @DragonSlayer3 What is a "wrong time"?

Comment: I mean that the light wave is saying go up, while another is saying go down.

Comment: No it's not like that, as I was saying, in Classical theory according to the principle of Superposition the fields do not interact with each other.
But in quantum theory scattering takes place.

Comment: So, it's impossible to guide a beam of light in a magnetic field like they do in accelerators?

Answer (score 3):

Light is an **[electromagnetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation)** wave. To be precise light is an oscillating electric and magnetic field.

Secondly, no light is not affected by other magnetic fields by external sources in vacuum. This is primarily due [Principle of Superposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle#Other_example_applications) which states that fields themselves don't interact with each other. (In classical theory). But remember, light can affect the behaviour of electron. As the light wave is an oscillating field, hence the electron moves to and fro and there is no net motion, but if you could observe an electron as light propagates you'd see it moving/oscillating to and fro, but still it's net position wouldn't change.

But if the situation is not in vacuum then light waves passing by matter are affected by matter: slowed down, bent, absorbed, maybe even distorted into other frequencies of wave.

Electric and magnetic fields can modify these interaction parameters of a substance, depending a lot on which substance it is.

Comment: So in a vacuum it is completely impossible for light to be affected in any way by other magnetic fields no matter how strong?

Comment: Yes, physics has it that in a vacuum, photons do nothing to photons. So light waves (electromagnetic waves) are nominally unaffected by magnetic and electric fields.